# How to get data from 2 activities or more and display their data in a single table (mysql)

Tags: php, android, database

My question is how is it possible to get data from 2 different activities and store their data in the same database
Example in the first activtiy the user inputs their name and email password and location
Then in the second activity the user inputs their prefered marker from a spinner(dropdown).
Now I want these data to be stored in the same row i.e same id which resides to the same table

Database structure of table one

Pk id

Name

Email

Password

Location

Marker (value is stored in the separate table)

Table 2 -second activity

Id pk

Marker

Comment: If they are two different activities, why do you want to store them in the same record?

Comment: Since I have a user registration where I populate it s data from more than one screen

Comment: Why don't you try with fragments?

Comment: If a user can have multiple activities, it's better to have a "user"-table with the user info and a "activity"-table (one-to-many) with the users activities. The activities-table should then contain a "user_id" column (which is a foreign key to the user-table). Then you can add how many activities you want for each user.

Comment: are you asking how to insert row and then get id of inserted row and use it in another insert into the other table ?

Comment: No basically I have two activities which I want to use to populate my whole table example having a table with x and y attributes. The first activity will populate the x coloumn while the second activity will populate the y coloumn basically the population will happen after each other but not at the same time